# How to add an extra sku field to all products?

Tags: magento-1.8

I'm just trying to add an extra sku field to all products, which is not showed in frontend but searchable in backend. I mean users or guests wont be able to see this extra sku but i will be able to search the products by this field. still not solved.

Comment: are you want to searchable sku when from frontend from cataog search

Comment: No, the sku that i want will be searchable on just backend (admin panel).

Comment: where you want to do this give a screen shot

Comment: in catalog/manage products section. Just like "SKU" - "OLD SKU".

Comment: http://i.hizliresim.com/b4dMyZ.png

Comment: and it has to be editable from here (under the SKU field, OLD SKU) http://i.hizliresim.com/B956rL.png

Comment: You need create custom module and which will  have a product  and show all product with here

Comment: If i could create a custom module by myself, i wouldnt ask this question here.

Comment: your was  question too unclear.it is too many possiable answer...

Comment: Ok, can anybody else help me?

Comment: it is still not solved

Comment: Add the column in the admin grid via observer. As it has been said, it's not possible without custom module, so if you don't know where to start, you'll have to find a developer to implement it. Magento is not a system for tinkerers.

Comment: Look the answer below writen by R.S and think again what you aim for. Help or ego satisfaction.

Answer (score 1):

Listed below are 2 of the several ways of accomplishing this. To answer this question will required writing too much code, so please choose a method and if you have any additional issue please ask a more specific question base on your choice.

Correct way  - [stackoverflow.com : Add column to Magento admin catolog > manage products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990910/add-column-to-magento-admin-catolog-manage-products/5994209#5994209)

Quick Way - [Magento: Add attribute columns in ‘Manage Products’ grid](http://www.leonhostetler.com/blog/magento-add-attribute-columns-in-manage-products-grid-201205/)